# Why is the power series representation for $\ln(1-x^2)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2 n}}{n}$ and not $\sum _{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, logarithms, power-series

I am working on finding a power series representation of $\ln(1-x^2)$ and am getting a wrong answer according to [this answer key](https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-2/pages/chapter-6#fs-id1167023803877-solution) (problem 97.) I would like to understand why my answer is wrong and their answer is right. First I differentiate $\ln(1-x^2)$ to be $\frac {1}{1-x^2}$ which I get as  $\sum _{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}$ using the fact that $\frac 1 {1-x^2} =\sum _{n=0} ^\infty x^n$. Then I integrate $\sum _{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}$ as $\sum _{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$ by integrating the generic term in the body of the sum. However, the answer is $-\int_{t=0}^{x^2} \frac{1}{1-t} d t=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{x^2} t^n d x-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2(n+1)}}{n+1}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2 n}}{n}$, which is different than my answer of $\sum _{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$.
I have 4 questions here:

1. I have chosen to integrate $\frac 1 {1-x^2}$; how is  $\int_{t=0}^{x^2} \frac 1 {1-t}dx$ related to this and why would we perform this computation rather than what I integrated?
2. How does the second expression in the equations hold? I do not understand it.
3. How does definite integration of power series work here? The textbook only discusses indefinite integration
4. Why is my answer wrong?

UPDATE: I have understood why my derivative is wrong as the comment helpfully pointed out. However, my confusion with the original answer still stands.

Comment: Your derivative of $\ln(1-x^2)$ is incorrect.

Comment: An alternative way of checking that the solution from the book is correct: putting $x^2$ instead of $x$ in $\ln(1 - x) = - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$.

Comment: $\frac{d}{d x}\left[\ln \left(1-x^2\right)\right]=\frac{-2 x}{1-x^2} \neq \frac{1}{1-x^2}$

Comment: The function $\ln(1-x^2)$ is even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(x) = \ln(1-x)$. Then, $\ln(1-x^2) = F(x^2)$. We know that $F(x) = -\int_0^x\frac{1}{1-t}\,dt + F(0)$, and since $F(0) = 0$, we have $F(x^2) = -\int_0^{x^2}\frac{1}{1-t}\,dt$. The idea here is that if $F(x) = \sum a_nx^n$, then $F(x^2) =\sum a_nx^{2n}$, so basically, you are calculating series expansion of $\ln(1-x)$ (which comes from the integral $-\int\frac{dt}{1-t}$) and plugging in $x^2$ in the formula.

You can do it your way as well, we have $\frac d{dx}\ln(1-x^2) = \frac{-2x}{1-x^2} $, so $$\ln(1-x^2) = -2\int_0^x\frac{t}{1-t^2}\,dt = -2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^x t^{2n+1}\,dt = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+2}}{n+1} = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{n}.$$

The difference between definite and indefinite integration here is minor. Let's say that we want power series expansion of $F(x)$, and that we know power series expansion of $f(x) = \frac d{dx} F(x)$. Above we used the formula $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt + F(0)$, which explains why definite integration works. If you used indefinite integration, what you would use instead is $\int f(x)\,dx = F(x)+C$. So, if you knew that $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$, we get
$$F(x) + C = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\int x^n\,dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}.$$ You still want to calculate $C$ and you can do it by plugging in $x = 0$ to get $F(0)+C = 0$, so $F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + F(0)$. Notice the similarity with the formula we had before with definite integration. Essentially, the difference is that definite integration automatically takes care of "$+C$" we get from indefinite integration.

Comment: For $\ln(1-x^2) = -2\int_0^x\frac{t}{1-t^2}\,dt$, can you explain the logic behind choosing the bounds of integration to be $0$ and $x$ and why we integrate with respect to $t$ not $x$?

Comment: @Shmuel You can't integrate against $x$ because an integration variable is silent, it cannot be relying on "external" variables. The $0$ bound is because $\ln(1 - 0^2) = 0$, while the $x$ bound is the standard way to compute the antiderivative of a given continuous function (see the aptly named fundamental theorem of calculus).

Comment: @Shmuel, as Bruno said, I'd strongly advise you to revisit the [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements). Everything I wrote in this answer is direct application of it. I can see there is a chapter dedicated to it in the book you linked.

Comment: @Shmuel, explicitly, what I did there is what I wrote later: $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt + F(0)$ with $F(x) = \ln(1-x^2)$, $f(x) = \frac{-2x}{1-x^2}$, which follows from Newton-Leibniz formula $\int_0^x f(t)\,dt = F(x) - F(0)$ because $F$ is antiderivative of $f$. For the bounds I choose $x$ as the upper bound because I want formula for $F(x)$ in terms of integral because we know power series expansion of $f$, and $F(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

A. Using the expansion,

\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{1-t}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} t^n, \forall|t|<1, \\
\int_0^{x^2} \frac{1}{1-t} d t&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{x^2} t^n d t \\
-\ln \left(1-x^2\right)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2(n+1)}}{n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2 n}}{n}
\end{aligned}

B.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{1}{1-x^2} d x & =\frac{1}{2} \int\left(\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{1+x}\right) d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right|+C
\end{aligned}
$$
C.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{x^2} \frac{1}{1-t} d t & =-[\ln |1-t|]_0^{x^2} \\
& =-\ln \left|1-x^2\right|
\end{aligned}
$$
D. Noting that for any $|x|<1$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{d x}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2 n+1}}{2 n+1}\right)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{d x}\left(\frac{x^{2 n+1}}{2 n+1}\right) \\
& =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{2 n} \\
& =\frac{1}{1-x^2}
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2 n+1}}{2 n+1} =\int \frac{1}{1-x^2} d x=\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right|+C 
$$
Putting $x=0$ yields $C=0$ and hence
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2 n+1}}{2 n+1}=\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right|
$$
Wish it helps!